# VSTS to Zendesk Plugin

Tags: azure-devops, zendesk

We are trying to set up the [Team Services to Zendesk app](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-zendesk-app), but we are getting an error when we try to upload it into Zendesk, "Missing required key from translations/en.json: app.name".  Anyone else gone through the uploading of this App, or have an idea of what we may need to do to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

It’s caused by the **Zendesk Apps framework (ZAF) V1 hasn’t been supported by Zendesk since Aug 1st 2017**.

> Beginning August 1st, 2017, Zendesk will no longer permit uploads of
> new private apps using the v1 framework.
>
> [Learn more](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004453028-Announcing-Sunset-Apps-Framework-v1)

To upload the private app (*.zip) to Zendesk, you should use framework v2.

I posted an issue to suggested [change the code for vsts-zendesk-app with Zendesk Apps framework v2](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-zendesk-app/issues/37) correspondingly, you can follow up.

The work around for now is migrate farmework from v1 to v2 manually. You can refer [Migrating to v2](https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/apps-v2/migrating) for details.

Answer (score 0):

try this app

https://www.zendesk.com/apps/support/integratecloud-connector-for-vsts/?q=mkp_vsts

Azure DevOps (VSTS) Integration App by IntegrateCloud, allows the users to create Azure DevOps (VSTS) work items right inside the Zendesk form. It also allows you to link existing Zendesk tickets to an existing Azure DevOps (VSTS) work items. In addition, it allows Agents to notify the Azure DevOps (VSTS) team, by sending comments inside Zendesk Support.

We also support customization based on customer request and tailored to your needs! We bring Azure DevOps (VSTS) closer to your business model!

The App has 5 buttons, 'New Work Item', 'Link Issue', 'Link to Work Item', 'Notify' & 'Show Item Comments'.

-New Work Item: When clicked on the New Work Item tab, select the type of work item you want to create Bug, Epic, Feature, Task, User Story etc. Based on the selection it will load all the Azure DevOps (VSTS) fields. The User can make the selection and click on Create button which would create work item in Azure DevOps (VSTS) and then display the corresponding Azure DevOps (VSTS) work item Id in the App.

-Link to Work Item: This tab allows you to link an existing Zendesk Ticket. It can be linked to one work item in Azure DevOps (VSTS) .

-Notify: This tab allows the user to send notifications to the Azure DevOps (VSTS) team which would show up as comments in Azure DevOps (VSTS) .

-Show Item Comments: This tab shows you all the linked Azure DevOps (VSTS) work item comments log to current Zendesk ticket.